# How do I get the HMODULE for the currently executing code?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a static library that may get linked into either a `.exe` or a `.dll`.  At runtime I want one of my library functions to get the `HMODULE` for whatever thing the static library code has been linked into.

I currently use the following trick (inspired from [this forum](http://www.ureader.com/message/1095160.aspx)):

```
const HMODULE GetCurrentModule()
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = {0};
    ::VirtualQuery( GetCurrentModule, &mbi, sizeof(mbi) );

    return reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(mbi.AllocationBase);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't look so hacky?

*(Note: The purpose of this is to load some Win32 resources that I know my users will have linked in at the same time as my static library.)*

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/119706/946850

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
HMODULE GetCurrentModule()
{ // NB: XP+ solution!
  HMODULE hModule = NULL;
  GetModuleHandleEx(
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
    (LPCTSTR)GetCurrentModule,
    &hModule);

  return hModule;
}
```

Comment: Cool.  I remember now that when I wrote my GetCurrentModule() function we had to support Windows 2000.  Which is why I used the VirtualQuery() hack instead of GetModuleHandleEx().

Comment: GLad to help. Out of curiosity, why did you prefer my solution over the __ImageBase one?

Comment: Probably due to not understanding how Windows fixes up symbol addresses.

Comment: Note that if this succeeds, it increases the refcount on the module, so you'll need to call `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: @Adrian: Or use GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT.

Comment: @Amnon this however returns the handle from the host in my case from the executable and not the dll that was called into.

Comment: I believe that Annon intended to suggest that you combine GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT with GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, via bitwise OR, like so:GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT. This is exactly how I implemented a call to get the instance handle of my C++ unit test module, without resorting to writing a DLLMain routine of my own.

Comment: You save the bacon! Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

`__ImageBase` is a linker generated symbol that is the DOS header of the module (MSVC only). From that you can cast its address to an `HINSTANCE` or `HMODULE`. So it's more convenient than going through an API.

So you just need to do this:

```
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#define HINST_THISCOMPONENT ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase)
```

From https://web.archive.org/web/20100123173405/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx

Comment: According to the link in my original question, the __ImageBase is only the preferred loading address, not always the actual loading address.

Comment: You doubt Raymond Chen? The discussion at the link demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of a linker constant, but the final comment is correct.

Comment: Err... __ImageBase is a symbol. If it weren't fixed up when the .dll or .exe is loaded, neither would any other symbol and everything would break. Therefore, it's valid to use it since its address is fixed up at image load time.

Comment: And the discussion at Raymond Chen's blog has a good discussion about the horrible side effects of GetCurrentModule (not Ex).

Comment: @MSN: I guess the remark on `GetCurrentModule` is a typo, as there is no such symbol in the Windows API. What were you referring to, and which comments discuss those side effects (and what are they)?

Comment: @MSN: That's the same link you posted in your answer already, and it doesn't mention `GetCurrentModule`. I assume you meant to say `GetModuleHandle`. But even then, neither the blog entry nor the comments mention any side effects.

Comment: @IInspectable What side effects are you referring to? The side effects of directly referencing `__ImageBase`? It's a symbol. There are no side effects.

Comment: @MSN: I was referring to your comment above: *"Raymond Chen's blog has a good discussion about the horrible side effects of GetCurrentModule (not Ex)"*. I assume that should read *"horrible breakage*" instead, as there are no side effects either. Not trying to split hairs. Just wanted to make sure that I haven't overlooked any pitfalls I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I don't know which version introduced support for `__ImageBase`, but both Clang's `lld` and GCC's `ld` support it as well. It's no longer *"MSVC only"*.

Answer (score 5):

I'd look at `GetModuleHandleEx()` using the flag `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS`. It looks like you can change your `GetCurrentModule()` to call this routine instead of `VirtualQuery()`, and pass the address of `GetCurrentModule()` as the `lpModuleName` argument.

ETA:

```
const HMODULE GetCurrentModule()
{
    DWORD flags = GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS;
    HMODULE hm = 0;
    ::GetModuleHandleEx( flags, reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>( GetCurrentModule ), &hm );   
    return hm;
}
```

I didn't try it, but I think that'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1300  // for VC 7.0 
#ifndef _delayimp_h 
extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase; 
#endif
#endif
... 
HMODULE module() 
{ 
#if _MSC_VER < 1300  // earlier than .NET compiler (VC 6.0) 
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi; 
    static int address; 
    ;::VirtualQuery(&address, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)); 
    return reinterpret_cast(mbi.AllocationBase); 
#else  // VC 7.0 
    // from ATL 7.0 sources 
  return reinterpret_cast(&__ImageBase); 
#endif 
}
```

More here https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/74-hmodule-hinstance-handle-from-static-library-in-c

Comment: VC6 linker supports __ImageBase.

Answer (score -4):

The HMODULE is the HINSTANCE is the base address of the module. So, I'd see how it worked. But if all you want is the HMODULE of the executable, why not enumerate all HMODULE's in the process (EnumProcessModules). One of them will have your .lib linked in.

The limitation I see is that you have no idea which DLL or EXE your .lib comes from. You might want to compare the HMODULEs (base addresses) against the _ReturnAddress you get from your .lib. Your .lib will belong to the highest HMODLUE smaller than your _ReturnAddress

Comment: Enumerating a list of modules is very inefficient, and not nearly as tidy as calling GetModuleHandleEx. Let's see; get the answer I need with a single, fast API call, or loop through potentially dozens of modules, performing string comparisons (VERY expensive!) as I go. I think I'll take the shortcut.