# What can I do about loading this resource into a unit testing DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I just ported all of my tests from Google Test to Visual Studio 2012's unit test framework. (Long story; Google's assertions are better but Microsoft's works with the Dev11 Unit Test Explorer out of the box, which makes getting code coverage really easy ...)

I got everything ported over fine, except for the following class, which reads a newline-delimited text file from a Win32 resource, and then allows for quick lookups against that resource:

```
#include "pch.hpp"
#include "resource.h"
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Win32Exception.hpp"
#include "Whitelist.hpp"

using Instalog::SystemFacades::Win32Exception;

namespace Instalog {

    Whitelist::Whitelist( __int32 whitelistId , std::vector<std::pair<std::wstring, std::wstring>> const& replacements )
    {
        using namespace std::placeholders;

        HRSRC resourceHandle = ::FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(whitelistId), L"WHITELIST");
        if (resourceHandle == 0)
        {
            Win32Exception::ThrowFromLastError();
        }
        HGLOBAL resourceGlobal = ::LoadResource(0, resourceHandle);
        if (resourceGlobal == 0)
        {
            Win32Exception::ThrowFromLastError();
        }
        void * resourceData = ::LockResource(resourceGlobal);
        if (resourceData == 0)
        {
            Win32Exception::ThrowFromLastError();
        }
        wchar_t const* resourceDataCasted = static_cast<wchar_t const*>(resourceData);
        DWORD resourceLen = ::SizeofResource(0, resourceHandle);
        auto sourceRange = boost::make_iterator_range(resourceDataCasted, resourceDataCasted + (resourceLen / sizeof(wchar_t)));
        boost::algorithm::split(innards, sourceRange, std::bind1st(std::equal_to<wchar_t>(), L'\n'));
        std::for_each(innards.begin(), innards.end(), std::bind(boost::algorithm::to_lower<std::wstring>, _1, std::locale()));
        std::for_each(innards.begin(), innards.end(), [&replacements] (std::wstring &a) {
            std::for_each(replacements.begin(), replacements.end(), [&a] (std::pair<std::wstring, std::wstring> const&b) {
                if (boost::algorithm::starts_with(a, b.first))
                {
                    a.replace(a.begin(), a.begin() + b.first.size(), b.second);
                }
            });
        });
        std::sort(innards.begin(), innards.end());
    }

    bool Whitelist::IsOnWhitelist( std::wstring checked ) const
    {
        boost::algorithm::to_lower(checked);
        return std::binary_search(innards.begin(), innards.end(), checked);
    }

    void Whitelist::PrintAll( std::wostream & str ) const
    {
        std::copy(innards.begin(), innards.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(str, L"\n"));
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, Dev11's test projects generate DLLs, not EXEs, as under Google Test's system. So, while before I was able to embed the resource into the EXE and pass `NULL` to `FindResource`'s first parameter, now Visual Studio is loading the DLL into its process during testing. Visual Studio certainly doesn't have my custom `WHITELIST` resource type inside, so this code blows up.

Is there some way I can either

1. Tell this code somehow to look in the right binary, either the testing DLL or the EXE, depending on context? (Currently this code is in a static library which gets linked with both the real EXE and the testing DLL) or
2. Embed relatively large (a few MB) text files into a C++ program cleanly without using the Win32 resource infrastructure at all?

It should be noted that putting the resource into a satellite DLL (which might have been a reasonable solution) is not an option; a requirement of this project is single EXE xcopy deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I used the `GetCurrentModule` hack here -> [How do I get the HMODULE for the currently executing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557081/how-do-i-get-the-hmodule-for-the-currently-executing-code) . This gave the the HMODULE I needed to pass into the XxxResource APIs.