# Setting button icon using C with raw Win32

Tags: c, windows, winapi, win32gui

I'm building a GUI with some simple dialogs using raw Win32 API with pure C (no MCF).
In one of those dialog I'd like to display a button with an icon (a small folder) instead of a text.

I prepared a .ico file with the proper size (16x16 pixel) and I proceeded as follow:

- I've defined the icon resource in resource header file:

  ```
   #define ICON_FOLDER 901
  ```
- I've put the icon, called folder.ico, in the same folder of the resource script and I've loaded icon resource in it:

  ```
  ICON_FOLDER ICON "folder.ico"
  ```
- I've defined my button in the corresponding dialog resource specifying the `BS_ICON` style (`MODEL_SEARCH` is the resource ID defined in the resource header too):

  ```
  CONTROL "", MODEL_SEARCH, "button", BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_ICON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,   300, 8, 18, 18
  ```
- In the GUI code, when the dialog containing the button is built, I've tried to load the icon at the beginning of the dialog procedure and then tried to set the icon in the case `WM_INITDIALOG` using respectively the following two loines of code:

  ```
  HICON folderico=LoadIcon(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_FOLDER));
  ```

  and

  ```
  SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd,MODEL_SEARCH),BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_ICON,(LPARAM)folderico);
  ```

It doesn't work, the **button is displayed but it doesn't show the icon**.

I tried to do some changes and for example if I use those two last line of code to set one of default icons, like for example the `IDI_APPLICATION` one, the icon corresponding to `IDI_APPLICATION` resource is properly shown.

Comment: Does your icon's mask contain non-transparent pixels? Also, what happens if you copy the application icon over the *folder.ico* file?

Comment: Yes, my icon contains some non-trasparent pixels, but it should be not a problem, I used a similar icon as main window one and it's properly displayed... what do you mean for "copying the application icon", do you mean the executable? In this case nothing happens, anyway specifying the icon resource in the resource file it should be necessary the presence of the .ico file in the same directory of the resource script only at the resource file compiling time...

Comment: ps: I also tried to use another custom icon, the one that I use as th emain application icon (and  which I know to be properly load and displayed), but nothing changes...

Comment: There's no obvious sign of you having performed any error checking.  Of course, it doesn't help that you didn't show your code.  Had you shown your code we would know and not need to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` into the first parameter of LoadIcon. You only want to use NULL for the first argument if you are loading standard Windows icons.

Comment: Better would be to pass the actual module handle so that the code could run in a DLL if that were ever needed

Comment: It works, thank you!
Just for further information one can use the LoadImage function intead of the LoadIcon one, so that icon size can be trimmed at loading time.
It's also possible to compress load and set in only one row, as follow:

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd,MODEL_SEARCH),BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_ICON,(LPARAM)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_FOLDER),IMAGE_ICON,14,14,0));

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is technically true. To the poster, the solution I provided works if you are making an EXE.  In an EXE the hInstance passed in to WinMain() is the same as the one returned by GetModuleHandle(NULL).  If this code was in a DLL you would want to keep track of the hInstance from DllMain() and supply it as the first argument to LoadIcon instead.

Comment: Yes, I know how `GetModuleHandle` works.  If using the MS compiler you can use `__ImageBase` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557081/how-do-i-get-the-hmodule-for-the-currently-executing-code

Comment: @FilippoMicheletti Please do take this as a sign that you need to check for errors. Had you done so you'd have realised that `LoadIcon` was failing. This is your opportunity to learn from experience that failing to check for errors causes pain.