# CreateDialog in BHO always fails with error 1813 (resource not found)

Tags: c++, winapi, bho

I'm working on a BHO written a long time ago in C++, without the use of any of the VS wizards. As a result, this project deviates from the COM conventions and the boilerplate for a COM product. I worked with COM long ago, but never really did any Windows GUI/dialog stuff...

I'm trying to add a dialog box to allow the user to set the values of some new settings:

```
// serverDialog will be NULL
HWND serverDialog = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_PROPPAGE_SETTINGS), NULL, DialogProc);

id (!serverDialog) 
{
    int error = GetLastError(); //1813
    ...
}

....
```

1813 means that the resource cannot be found. The IDD used there is in resource.h, which I manually included where needed.

DialogProc is defined as:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Which I know I will have to change later if I want the dialog to actually process messages, but I haven't gotten that far yet. The 1813 error suggests failure before the dialog is even created as does the NULL dialog handle returned.

To add the dialog I used the Add Resource wizard and added a small property page.

I've tried to follow advice [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/printthread.php?t=377230), but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe resource is not in `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. Test it with `GetModuleHandle("fullpath")` where "fullpath" is the exe/ocx/dll which holds the resource.

Comment: The error message is unequivocal. The resource is not there. You passed an instance of `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` which is the process module. But your BHO is surely in a DLL. So why would the resource be in the process module? Don't you need to pass the instance for your module?

Comment: [Accessing the current module's HINSTANCE from a static library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan right you are! I also needed to change the third parameter from NULL to the the browser window handle to avoid a "no parent window" error, but now the dialog is created. Still having trouble showing it, but that's another can of worms. If you answer the question, I will accept the answer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani right you are as well - see my answer to Mr Heffernan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` as the instance of the module that contains the resource. But `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` defines the executable file module. You need to pass the instance of the module containing your code. This question covers that topic: [How do I get the HMODULE for the currently executing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557081/how-do-i-get-the-hmodule-for-the-currently-executing-code)

You probably ought to pass a window handle to the `hWndParent` parameter so that the dialog is owned.