# DLL hinstance with in the same dll

Tags: dll, mfc, hinstance

I have an MFC dll with is used in an application.This Dll doesn't have DLLMain function.Now how do i retrieve hinstance of the said dll with in the dll?I am using VS 2010.

Comment: Doesn't [AfxGetInstanceHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36z3tfsb(v=vs.100).aspx) work for you?

Comment: no not working.i tried all the methods specified in this form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the HMODULE for the currently executing code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557081/how-do-i-get-the-hmodule-for-the-currently-executing-code)

Answer (score 1):

GetModuleHandle function will return the HINSTANCE of the dll or the exe.
Pass the name of your dll as the first argument.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx