# Resource file not loading for a DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll

My code for loading the file from resource is given below

```
    void LoadFileInResource(int name, int type, DWORD& size, const char*& data)
{
    HMODULE handle = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC rc = ::FindResource(handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(name),MAKEINTRESOURCE(type));
    HGLOBAL rcData = ::LoadResource(handle, rc);
    size = ::SizeofResource(handle, rc);
    data = static_cast<const char*>(::LockResource(rcData));
}
```

This code works perfect if its just an application. When the same code is used as a DLL, I am getting null in rc, which is post the FindResource.

I have defined the symbols in resourceful file as shows below:

```
#define TEXTFILE        256
#define IDR_MYTEXTFILE  105
```

Also the file which I need to add is defined in rc file:

```
IDR_MYTEXTFILE TEXTFILE "C:/Docs/Lib.XML"
```

As I mentioned earlier, this code is perfectly working when its an application, converting it to DLL is creating issue.

LoadFileInResource function is called as given below:

```
LoadFileInResource(IDR_MYTEXTFILE, TEXTFILE, size, data);
```

Comment: Should I get the module handle in dllmain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557081/how-do-i-get-the-hmodule-for-the-currently-executing-code solved my query. thanks.