# Win api - error 1813 after calling LoadImage

Tags: winapi

I have a dynamic library which uses `LoadImage` function:

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)(LONG_PTR)GetWindowLongPtr(wnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE);
HBITMAP hBitMap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resId), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

That library is linked to the main application (exe). When the application calls a library function which calls LoadImage I get Win api error 1813. hInstance refers to the exe file. How to fix that ?

Comment: The error text is `"The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file."`. Maybe your `resId` is invalid.

Comment: @wohlstad resId is correct.

Comment: Think that problem lies you want load image from dll but instead your code trying to load resource from exe.

Comment: `GetWindowLongPtr(wnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)` is wrong. you must take `hInstance` from `&__ImageBase` if it in your dll, or from LoadLibraryW/GetModuleHandleW if it in another dll/exe

Comment: In other words, it is using the wrong `HINSTANCE` to load from.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadImage` works when I get `HINSTANCE` this way:

```
HMODULE GetModule()
{ 
    HMODULE hMod = NULL;
    GetModuleHandleEx(
        GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
        (LPCTSTR)GetModule,
        &hMod);

    return hMod;
}

HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModule();
```

Please review my answer.

Comment: `hInstance = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase`

Comment: Where ```__ImageBase``` is defined ? Which header should I include ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/557859/6401656 if you search - you found alot of links. And if you search in header files - you found where it defined

Comment: How it differ from my answer ?

Comment: `(HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase` this is simply use constant. you use 2 api calls, which not need

Comment: `__ImageBase` is a pseudo linker variable that gets dropped into the .obj with an RVA of 0 by the linker. The net result is that determining the `HMODULE` of the module that contains the currently executing code is just a memory lookup. No function calls, and no error handling required. It is supported by MS' link.exe, lld (Clang), and ld (GCC).